# Selecting using LINQ directly to Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

State today is as follows.

```
IEnumerable<Beep>
  as = list.Where(e => e.Name == "A").Select(e => e.Property),
  bs = list.Where(e => e.Name == "B").Select(e => e.Property);
Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Beep>> 
  = new Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Beep>>()
    { { "A", as }, { "B", bs } };
```

I wonder how it can be refactored to make the dictionarization directly from the LINQ expression in one statement.

Comment: `Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Beep>>` !=  `Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<String>>` Can you provide compiling code? This is confusing enough.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review of working code.

Comment: @Servy It's not about code review at all. It's a question on how to perform said tasks in one statement, if at all possible.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You're specifically asking for the reader's opinion of your working code, and asking if anyone sees a way of making it "better".  That's a code review.

Comment: @TimSchmelter My bad. I'm testing while asking. Corrected the code.

Comment: @Servy You're right. Reformulated the question. I didn't mean to ask for opinions but it sure might be interpreted as such request. Should've been more clear and to the point.

Comment: How is the question **opinion based** now, for frog's sake?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are getting a `IEnumerable<Beep>` you don't really want `ToDictionary()`, instead this is kind of what [`ToLookup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does.

```
var result = list.ToLookup(x => x.Name, x => x.Property);
```

this will output a `ILookup<string, Beep>` which is equivalent to a `Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Beep>>`

Important note! One cavate to doing it this way is the resulting ILookup can not be further modified to add more items later where having a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Beep>>` would allow you to add more items after the initial creation. If you want a dictionary you would need to do

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Name)
  .ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x=>x.Select(y=> y.Property));
```

Comment: if type of the Property is `IEnumerable<Beep>` how does `.ToLookup(x => x.Name, x => x.Property);` return an `ILookup<string, string>`?

Comment: @Selman22 If type of Property is `IEnumerable<Beep>` then the first version will output a `ILookup<string, Beep>` and the second will be changed too, that is one of the nice reasons to use `var` you are less likely to need to modify your code if datatypes change.

Comment: No, it will return `ILookup<string, IEnumerable<Beep>>`

Comment: the information you have given is incorrect, I'm saying if Property is a `IEnumerable<Beep>` then `.ToLookup(x => x.Name, x => x.Property);` will return an `ILookup<string, IEnumerable<Beep>>` , and sorry but, `Select(y=>y)` doesn't flatten anything

Comment: @Selman22 sure, you are absoulty correct but I don't think Property is a `IEnumerable<Beep>`, if it was in the OP's original example his data type would need to be `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Beep>> as = list.Where(e => e.Name == "A").Select(e => e.Property)`.

Comment: yes I also thought it was `IEnumerable<Beep>` since from the beginning haven't noticed the `Select` part =) sorry for the confusion